# Laravel paginate not working with select certain columns on querybuilder

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.5

I have user role relation (many to many) defined as follows in Role model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Now I want to show all users in certain role. I execute the following:

```
$list = Role::find(1)->users()->select('name')->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

Here `$list` contain all users that belong to role with id 1 and that is correct. But the problem is: when adding breakpoint on `$list` it shows that: all user model's attributes are retrieved just like `select('name')` has no effect.
This is a big problem especially when i want to return the `$list` as json. User password is retrieved even though it's in the `$hidden` array of User Model.
My question is:

why `paginate()` on querybuilder does not respect `select()` nor attributes in model's `$hidden` array?

Note: I know that there is other solutions to achieve what I want. I just want an answer to my question to figure out what is going on?

Comment: U use FIND() in bad way. Read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select('name')` has no effect because *paginate()* method takes columns as second parameter

```
$list = Role::find(1)->users()->orderBy('name')->paginate(10, ['name']);
```

You can read more about parameters and methods here
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Answer (score 1):

Since users have the `role_id` then why don't you fetch the users as:

```
User::where('role_id', 1)->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

You are basically getting a role and then fetching a list against that role.

Comment: I know that but my question is not that. my question is  why paginate() on querybuilder does not respect select()?

Comment: I get it now, I will need to check the code to know what's going on, got your point though